# Is a popular site like www.google.com served up by one computer?

Tags: networking

In basic networking, we talk about DNS servers, that they resolve human readable addresses (www.google.com) into an actual IP address. As far as I understand, at least using the basics, an IP address refers to a single device (say a router). Surely, www.google.com cannot be served up by one computer? How is www.google.com distributed across multiple servers?

Comment: load balancing, [dns based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29#Round-robin_DNS) is the easy one

Comment: [A row of Google Servers in Google's Oklahoma Data Center](http://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Take-a-Look-%E2%80%93-Google-Data-Centre-11.jpg)

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform

Comment: You should also do an `nslookup www.google.com` - I get 5 different addresses there, which then get further distributed.

Comment: Great question, but it appears to be off-topic because it's more about networking than programming.

Comment: You may be interested in the beginnings of Google, when it really did run on one computer: http://royal.pingdom.com/2009/03/02/original-google-setup-at-stanford-university/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about networking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is, its not.

First off, google is not servers by one IP address.  For me, when looking at Google's domain:

```
$ nslookup
> www.google.com
Server:     192.168.1.254
Address:    192.168.1.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.46.52
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.46.48
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.46.49
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.46.50
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.46.51
```

It is served by one of those 5 different IP addresses... for me.  However, tossing www.google.com into an online nslookup tool gives me:

```
173.194.115.115
173.194.115.112
173.194.115.116
173.194.115.113
173.194.115.114
```

For you, it could be different.

Google wants to serve its data to me as fast as it can.  So, instead of having me contact a machine in Mountain view, California I am instead contacting a machine that is somewhere closer to me (probably Chicago or Minneapolis for me).

That particular style of dns is known as [round robin dns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) and gives me one of those addresses.  Behind the address there is likely another pool of machines behind another [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29).  The load balancer is a machine (or set of machines) that takes individual queries and then sends to to another machine (or set of machines) that is least busy.

That said, there's *still* more machines behind that.  From Computer Weekly, an article from 2009: [Single Google search uses 1,000 servers](http://www.computerweekly.com/news/2240088495/Single-Google-search-uses-1000-servers).  I'm not sure if that is still accurate but it gives you an idea that there is not a single computer behind the search.

You may also find [Inside Search](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/howsearchworks/thestory/index.html) a useful bit to read - there is lots that can be said about search and how it works.  This [Google Talk](http://www.slideshare.net/hasanveldstra/the-anatomy-of-the-google-architecture-fina-lv11) is a set of slides that is also a good bit to read.

Comment: Are each of those IP addresses (e.g. 173.194.115.115) one device? (i.e. one server/machine?) As I understand it now, there is a (giant) pool of machines, each with their own IP address, that get round-robin-ed to distributed the load.

Comment: Each IP is likely one [Squid reverse proxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy) that sits at the edge of the Google Intranet that is closest to me. Each time I ask for www.google.com I get one of those addresses. There are lots of these squid reverse proxies around (from my office ~15 miles away from my home, I've got *another* set of 5 addresses).